# min-height interaction with percent positioning

Tags: css

Why does percent positioning work with a fixed pixel height, but not with a min-height? More specifically, this code doesn't position the header along the y-axis at all:

```
#home {
    min-height: 715px;
    background-color: #F7F8F9;
    margin: 0;
}

#home h1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 6.67%;
    top: 30%;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

But this code does:

```
#home {
    height: 715px;
    background-color: #F7F8F9;
    margin: 0;
}

#home h1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 6.67%;
    top: 30%;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The only difference here is that the first example has a div with a min-height, while the second example has a div with a fixed height.

Comment: because the reference is always height and not min-height

Comment: ^ https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/#valdef-top-percentage

Comment: This is a statement from oficial MDN documentation on min-height: "The element's height is set to the value of min-height whenever min-height is larger than max-height or height.". By their own definition, this should work, by setting the height as 715px since you didn't set a greater height or any child made the home div bigger than that. The only reason I can see for that to not work would be if min-height didn't actually set the element's height.

Comment: @Pelicer min-height set the *computed* value of height in certain conditions but never the height value that remain auto that's why top cannot be resolved against height because it's auto.